# Post Multiple values as foreign key -- Django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model(ProfessionalMemberContacts) which has a primary key in different model(MasterProfessionalMembers).

ProfessionalMemberContacts expects multiple or single set of details as per user input
ie user could give multiple contact details.

**Problem:** I cant figure out the way to loop over all the contact details(if multiple) to save in "ProfessionalMemberContacts" with reference to "MasterProfessionalMembers".

Here is my relevant code for models and views for it.

Models.py

```
class ProfessionalMemberContacts(models.Model):
    professionalmemberId = models.ForeignKey(MasterProfessionalMembers, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pro_contact")
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class MasterProfessionalMembers(models.Model):
    professionalmemberId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100, default=1)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    incorp_date = models.DateField(default=date.today())
    organization_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create_pro_individual_member(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        contact_person = request.POST.getlist('contact_person')
        contact_email = request.POST.getlist('contact_email')
        contact_number = request.POST.getlist('contact_number')
        professionalmemberId =request.POST.get('professionalmemberId')
        member_object = MasterProfessionalMembers.objects.get(professionalmemberId=professionalmemberId)
            if len(contact_person) != 0:
                for p,ce,n in contact_person, contact_email, contact_number:
                    reference = ProfessionalMemberContacts(
                    contact_person = p,
                    contact_email = ce,
                    contact_number = n,
                    professionalmemberId = member_object
                    )
                    reference.save()
            return HttpResponse('professionalmember Id created as: '+professionalmemberId)
```

**EDIT:** Changed the input value fields to `request.POST.getlist(<value>)`

**Note:** Expecting data and values in Form data.

Please suggest any way to save contact details provided by user.

**Request Data:** Testing in postman as Form data

```
professionalmemberId = 1234567
contact_person = abc
contact_email = abc@xyz.com
contact_number = 567789
contact_person = xyz
contact_email = xyz@abc.com
contact_number = 123456890
```

Comment: why do you have in the create_pro_individual_member function?

Comment: Can you share the request data?

Comment: @Rarblack, it will work as POST method for ```ProfessionalMemberContacts```

Comment: @bdbd Updated the post with request data expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for p,ce,n in zip(contact_person, contact_email, contact_number):
    ...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks a lot @bdbd. Saved the day!

Comment: No problem. Have fun!